# Incorrect selector is called on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is the following JS:

```
for (var catId in this.data.categories) {
  (function (catId) {
    $("li#tsCat-" + catId).click(function (event) {
      $(this).addClass("tax-active");
      event.stopPropagation();
    })
  }(catId))
  for (var floor in this.data.floors) {
    (function (floor, catId) {
      var selector = "#tsCatFloor_" + catId + "_" + floor;
      $(selector).on("click", function (event) {
        $(this).addClass("active-filt");
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
    }(floor, catId));
  }
}
```

This code forms two level list.
On clicking links on 1st level, it executes correct click handler `$("li#tsCat-" + catId)`.

But on clicking 2nd level it again executes 1st handler `$("li#tsCat-" + catId)`.
It needs to execute 2nd handler `$(selector)`.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't provided the full view, but what is good I found a solution what could be useful for everyone:
If You're adding .click() event be sure, that You put the data (against which .click is called) already to DOM. Otherwise .click will never be called.